# what is it better to include in the db asyncTask?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-asynctask

I want to wrap db access with asyncTask

which of the followings is better and why?

(a)

```
AsyncTask at = new AsyncTask
{

SavedOffersSQLiteHelper savedOffersSQLiteHelper = new SavedOffersSQLiteHelper();
savedOffersSQLiteHelper.addItem(..)

}
```

(b)

```
    public SavedOffersSQLiteHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // SQL statement to create book table
        String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "
                + TABLE_NAME
                + " ( "
                + "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + "uid VARCHAR(36))";

        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
    }


    public void addItem(Offer offer) {

///====== here ========
//AsyncTask ast = new AsyncTask {

        Log.d(MyLogger.TAG, "add saved-offer");
        // 1. get reference to writable DB
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        // 2. create ContentValues to add key "column"/value
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_UID, offer.getId().toString());


        // 3. insert
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, // table
                null, // nullColumnHack
                values); // key/value -> keys = column names/ values = column
                            // values

        String text = String.format("item was added to table: {0}", TABLE_NAME);
        Log.d(MyLogger.TAG, text);
        Toast.makeText(mContext, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

        // 4. close
        db.close();
// }
///====end asyncTasl======
    }
```

(c) other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement your database accessor class as a singleton instead, say, `MyDatabase`.

In it have an inner class extending `SQLiteHelper`, overriding `onCreate()` and `onUpdate()` as needed.

Create the object of that inner class in the constructor of your singleton. Then make your singleton provide the API you need. When implementing that API  your singleton will use its inner `SQLiteHelper`-derived class for `query()` and the likes.

Then, from everywhere, an `AsyncTask` included, use `MyDatabase.INSTANCE.myDbQuery()`

Singleton is the correct abstraction because you only have one single database (with many tables, probably though).

Comment: thanks. so AsyncTask will wrap the MyDatabase.INSTANCE.addItem() or will the AsyncTask be inside the addItem() method ?

Comment: addItem() will be inside AsyncTask's doInBackground(). Or it can be wherever you want it to be. There's no reason for an AsyncTask to be inside MyDatabase as AsyncTask is supposed to be tighten to an Activity, often resides within an Activity.